# Evaluating Integral involving hypergeometric function $\int_0^r (1+z^2)^{-N-k/2}z^{N-1}F(-k/2,-k/2,1- \frac{k+N}{2}; \frac{N}{2};(\frac{z}{r})^2) dz$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, hypergeometric-function, euler-lagrange-equation

As part of my Master thesis, I came across quite horrible integrals involving hypergeometric functions and hope someone here has insight in how to compute them explicitly.

Let $N\geq 2$ and $k\in (-N,0)$ and $F$ the hypergeometric function 2F1: https://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.21.0011.01.
I would like to compute the integrals

> > $$A( r):=\int_0^r (1+z^2)^{-N-k/2}z^{N-1}F(-k/2,1- \frac{k+N}{2}; \frac{N}{2};(\frac{z}{r})^2) dz$$ and
> > $$B( r ):=\int_r^{\infty} (1+z^2)^{-N-k/2}z^{N-1+k}F(-k/2,1-\frac{k+N}{2}; \frac{N}{2};(\frac{r}{z})^2) dz$$

The expressions involving $F$ are well-defined because $|\frac{z}{r}|<1$ if $z<r$ and $|\frac{r}{z}|<1$ if $z>r$.

There are plenty of questions about evaluating integrals involving hypergeometric functions, for instance: [Integral involving hypergeometric function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068788/integral-involving-hypergeometric-function). But here the arguments in $F$ are a bit more general.

There are many useful formulas involving integrals with hypergeometric functions. Note that F is of the form $F(a,a-b+1/2,b+1/2,.)$. Formula 15.3.17 in [https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf) seems useful to simplify the integrand:

$$F(a,b;2b;z)=(\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1-z})^{-2a}F(a,a-b+1/2;b+1/2;(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{1+\sqrt{1+z}})^2)$$ but it gives the wrong exponent for $(1+z^2)$.

**Background**: The question comes from verifying Euler-Lagrange equations/steady states of a Keller-Segel system, the integrals appear in Lemma 6 of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.07788.

I want to show that the function $\rho_{HLS}(r)=(\frac{1}{1+r^2})^{N+k/2}$ (as (slightly different) defined in equation (6.3) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08225) which maximises the HLS inequality $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n} \rho(x)\rho(y)|x-y|^k dxdy\leq C_{HLS}||\rho||_m^2$$ solves the Euler-Lagrange equations corresponding to the functional $$\mathcal{F}_2[\rho]_2=C_{HLS}||\rho||_m^2-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n} \rho(x)\rho(y)|x-y|^k dxdy,$$ that is $$2\left(\int \rho^m dx\right)^{\frac{2}{m}-1}\rho(x)^{m-1}-\rho(x)\ast |x|^k=0$$

Using Lemma 6 to rewrite $\rho(x)\ast |x|^k$ in polar coordinates using hypergeometric functions and with $||\rho_{HLS}||_m=(\frac{2^{1-N}\pi{\frac{N+1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{N+1}{2})})^{n+k/2}$ (see [Evaluate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+|x|^2}\right)^N dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266909/evaluate-int-mathbbrn-left-frac-lambda-lambda2x2-rightn-dx)), I want to check that

> > $$2^{\frac{3N-5}{2}}\pi^{\frac{N-1}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{N-1}{2})}{\Gamma(N-1)}(r^{k}A( r )+r^{-2n} B( r) )=\frac{2^{\frac{1+2(1-n)(2n+k)}{k}}\pi^{\frac{(n+1)(2n+k)}{k}}} {\Gamma(\frac{N+1}{2})^{\frac{2(2n+k)}{k}}}(\frac{1}{1+r^2})^{-k/2}$$

Comment: I think this is quite simple. Just subtitute $y=z^2$, and express the integrand by a product of two Meijer-G-Functions (https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/02/.) Then you two special cases for $r =1$ and $r=\inf$ a H-Fox-function of one variable and MeyerG-Function, respectively. In general a H-Fox-function of two variables.

Comment: Your function has 5 Arguments?

Comment: The more complexity of the solution is due to the sign of z in the prefactor of your integral: https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/21/01/02/02/

Comment: @stocha no sorry there should only be four arguments, just one with $k/2$

Comment: I checked this again, I think it is possible to express the integral in terms of the appell F1 or F3 function, which is a function of two variables, there are some special cases, when reduces to Hypergeometric 32F-function. Read this https://ur.booksc.eu/book/6426661/cfd1e9 (press pdf, 228 KB)

Comment: @stocha Hm, seems useful but struggle to change of variables; in the first integral I would like to have $x=0,y=r,-t/y=z^2,1-t/y=z^2/r^2$ then the second F and $t/x$ become undefined.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow you. I guess you have to write down your attempt, so I can help you. Since I have faced a similar integral in electrochemistry,, I already know the solution.

Comment: I am just comparing the integrals in the paper you linked with what I have. Putting $x=z/r,b=1,n=1,h=2,\sigma=1-N-k/2,\alpha=k/2, \beta=1-\frac{k+N}{2} $ in (1)  gives an integral from 0 to r of $z^{N-1}(1-(z/r)^2)^{-N-k/2}F(-k/2,1-\frac{k+N}{2}, a(z/r)^2,(z/r)^2)) dz$, but I want a plus and no factor of $1/r^2$ in the parenthesis and constant arguments in F except the last one.

Comment: You can simplify your integrals first by the substitution of $y=z^2$. Then you have to transform the integration limit, means the upper integration limit is 1. Your prefactor $(1+z)$ has to be expressed by a second hypergeometric function 2F1, Your argument "z" have two different signs, resulting in a appel-function of two variables. You are trying to find a solution with one variable. I have more time on weekend. Thanks.

Comment: Please invite me in a chat room, so I can exchange my way of solution